# Unable to execute data larger than 10Kb

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hue

I have Hadoop 1.3 installed on a server. Ambari is also installed allowing detailed viewing of the system. 
I have installed Hue and everything works well, however I have a pig script that will only work on very small data (2Kb) and when I try to increase the size of the data to > 10Kb (I repeated the data to see if this was the issue) it errors saying:

```
Message: Job failed! Error - # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit
```

If anybody can help that would be great. I have a feeling it's a configuration within mapred that I have to change but what I have tried doesn't seem to have done anything, hence my plee.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should look over the entire script, It could be due to an error parsing, it's likely to have some sort of typo on it, or  being misspell any path (input/output), or any other thing

Answer (score 2):

The error message you show looks like a secondary error: look in the logs to see *why* the map tasks are failing. It's almost certainly not linked to the amount of data, as 10KB is nothing. The number of map tasks started is dependent on the number of input files (or rather,the number of input *splits*): it looks as though you are increasing the number of files to process and thereby (inadvertently) including files that cause the failure.

Answer (score 0):

The link next to the 'Status' of the [running Pig job](http://gethue.tumblr.com/post/51559235973/tutorial-apache-pig-editor-in-hue-2-3) should provide even more details on the MapReduce error.